# Use line range within a fold

Tags: vim

Is it possible to restrict line range to within current fold? Say I want to do a substitution from second line through end of fold i.e.

```
2,$s/str/replace/
```

but I want it to apply to current fold only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are motions for jumping to the beginning of the current fold (`:help [z`) or to its end (`:help ]z`) but they don't have equivalent marks. If that were the case, one could do this with the *imaginary* `'*` mark:

```
:2,'*s/str/replace/
```

but that mark doesn't exist so it won't work.

One way to achieve what you want would be to visually select the area:

```
]zv[zj
```

and then do your substitution on the visual selection:

```
:'<,'>s/str/replace/
```

with the range `'<,'>` automatically inserted for you.

Or you could go the "grok vi" way and place manual marks:

```
]zme[zmb
```

before using them in your substitution:

```
:'b+,'es/str/replace/
```

but it seems less optimal than the "visual way".

Another solution would be to close the fold:

```
zc
```

and do the substitution on the closed fold, with confirmation so that you can skip the substitutions that occur on the first line:

```
:s/str/replace/c
```

So there are two approaches, here: one where care is put into defining the exact range and one where care is put into not substituting the wrong thing.